# How do I configure AMS admin permissions on EC2 AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-s3, permissions, adobe-media-server

I created a fresh [Adobe Media Server 5](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/adobemediaserver/configadmin/index.html) (aka Flash Media Server) instance on [Amazon EC2 AWS](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/), I connected over SSH and changed the default password, everything looks ok. But the amsadmin account doesn't seem to have enough access to administrate the instance. I can read most of the files and folders (access denied for /lib; /lost+found and /root).

**I can connect ok**

```
ssh -i key.pem amsadmin@public-dns.amazonaws.com
```

**I can upload to the media folder**

```
scp -i key.pem test.f4v amsadmin@public-dns.amazonaws.com:/mnt/applications/vod/media
```

**I can't upload content to webroot**; for example if I wanted to add a crossdomain.xml file to the web root.

```
scp -i key.pem crossdomain.xml amsadmin@public-dns.amazonaws.com:/mnt/webroot/
```

**I can't create a directory**; I want to [setup S3 to store content](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/adobemediaserver/amazonec2/WS6fc2df2b6d2ce2431afba23c12c3967d3ca-7ff1.2.3.1.html#WS0432746db30523c21e63e3d12c9b337c0c-8000.2.3.1), step 5 says to:

> Create a directory on the instance to mount the S3 bucket, for example, /mnt/s3fs.

But under the amsadmin account I get an access denied error, is this expected?

How can I get access to these restricted areas?

**Update:**

I tried executing the commands with `sudo` and I entered the correct password for amsadmin, got "Sorry, try again".

Do I need to setup a root account?

Comment: Since flash media server refers to v4 and Adobe media server refers to v5, you should make an adobe-media-server tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, I needed to run the commands using `sudo sh` after connecting to the instance via SSH.